# How to remove GNOME Web Browser

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, kde

I decided to switch from GNOME to KDE Plasma on Arch Linux, so I used `sudo pacman -Rdd gnome`. However, Web Browser remains, though with much less functionality (no tabs, etc.) Perhaps it was retained to keep KDE dependencies from breaking? I am very new to this, so I'm not sure what is going on. Any advice for how to clean this up?

[Pared Down Web Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY6Y9.png)
[How it appears in start menu (can't access any other way)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XyFB.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Try `sudo pacman -Rs epiphany`. `epiphany` is the package name of `GNOME Web Browser`.

Maybe it is a broken desktop file. Find and `sudo rm` from `/usr/share/applications/`.

Find and remove the package by tracking it from launcher:

1. Right click the launcher icon of the app to edit/view the entry.
2. Copy the executable path.
3. Use `pacman -Qo <copied path>` to see who owns the executable.
4. Remove the owner package.

Comment: I'm afraid ```pacman``` did not find ```epiphany```. I looked in ```/usr/share/applications/```, and I did not find ```epiphany``` or anything related to ```gnome```. However, I did find ```plasma-windowed.desktop```, and I think this is related. The icon on the taskbar says "plasmawindowed" when I hover over it. Does that indicate where this might be hiding?

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I used apt, and the issue is that KDE still thinks the app exists. If it's mainly on your KDE menu, you can remove it from the menu by right-clicking on the Menu button and selecting Edit Applications. Then find the GNOME Browser icon in the tree on the left. Then press Delete on your keyboard to remove the icon, then press Ctrl+S to save. This should remove the icon from the menu. Otherwise, I might try using `pacman -Qdt` to auto remove any dependincies that pacman may have not removed.